# struts and apache tomcat issue

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, struts2

I have run the web application done using struts. I not able to run the application i have faced the error while starting apache tomcat errors and while run the web application it also throws error .I have post the error log below and kindly help on this.I am new to netbeans Error in starting apache tomcat server

Please refer image

opentestdrive.com/demo/test/4.png,                        opentestdrive.com/demo/test/3.png
 opentestdrive.com/demo/test/2.png 
opentestdrive.com/demo/test/1.png

```
    Feb 04, 2016 3:19:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext     filterStartSEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Error while running the webapplication:

```
 Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/Loyalty4Salon
OK - Undeployed application at context path /Loyalty4Salon
In-place deployment at /home/revathy/Documents/Esa netbeans/loyalty_salon/loyalty_salon/build/web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext2062383266810619779.xml&path=/Loyalty4Salon
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /Loyalty4Salon but context failed to start
/home/revathy/Documents/Esa netbeans/loyalty_salon/loyalty_salon/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1125: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

This is the struts-config.xml

```
</form-beans>

<global-exceptions>

</global-exceptions>

<global-forwards>
    <forward name="welcome"  path="/Welcome.do"/>
</global-forwards>

<action-mappings>
    <action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp"/>
</action-mappings>

<controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor"/>

<message-resources parameter="com/myapp/struts/ApplicationResource"/>    

<!-- ========================= Tiles plugin ===============================-->
<!--
This plugin initialize Tiles definition factory. This later can takes some
parameters explained here after. The plugin first read parameters from
web.xml, thenoverload them with parameters defined here. All parameters
are optional.
The plugin should be declared in each struts-config file.
- definitions-config: (optional)
Specify configuration file names. There can be several comma
separated file names (default: ?? )
- moduleAware: (optional - struts1.1)
Specify if the Tiles definition factory is module aware. If true
(default), there will be one factory for each Struts module.
If false, there will be one common factory for all module. In this
later case, it is still needed to declare one plugin per module.
The factory will be initialized with parameters found in the first
initialized plugin (generally the one associated with the default
module).
true : One factory per module. (default)
false : one single shared factory for all modules
- definitions-parser-validate: (optional)
Specify if xml parser should validate the Tiles configuration file.
true : validate. DTD should be specified in file header (default)
false : no validation

Paths found in Tiles definitions are relative to the main context.
-->
<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin" >
    <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />      
    <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
</plug-in>

<!-- ========================= Validator plugin ================================= -->
<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
    <set-property
        property="pathnames"
        value="/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml,/WEB-INF/validation.xml"/>
</plug-in>
```

This is the struts.xml

```
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result> 
    <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="c_cpnDetail"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="c_cpnDetail" > 
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/cmpny_couponDetail.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action> 
<action name="coupon_index"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="couponCode" > 
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/coupon_create.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action> 
<action name="createCoupon"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="create_Coupon" >

    <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"/>                  
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="allowedTypes">
            image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
        </param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref> 
    <result name="invalid.token" type="redirect">coupon</result>
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result> 
    <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/ImageFileUploadError.jsp</result>
</action>  

<!--<action name="couponAssignPage"
class="com.Customer.Action"
 method="advSrch" > 
    <result name="success">./coupon_Assign.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">./error.jsp</result>
</action> -->

<action name="couponAssignPage"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="cpn_assignPage" > 
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/coupon_Assign.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="cpn_getUsers"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="cpn_getUsers" > 
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/coupon_Assign.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="coupon_assign"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="assign_coupon" > 
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>


<action name="couponAssign"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="coupon_assign"> 
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action> 
<action name="csvExport"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="csvExport"> 
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/csvDownload.jsp</result>

    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>        
<action name="search_usr"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="srch_usr1" > 
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/coupon_assign.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="deleteCoupon"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="dltCoupon" > 
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action> 
<action name="del_cpn"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="bulk_cpn_del" > 
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="c_edit"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="editCouponretrieve" > 
    <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/coupon_edit.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action> 
<action name="editCoupon"
        class="com.Customer.Action"
        method="editCoupon" > 
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="allowedTypes">
            image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
        </param>
```

Comment: Not able to fix that one

Comment: have you included  struts jars in the app package ?

Comment: yes...i am new to this..   see the image in this url                                                                          opentestdrive.com/demo/test/4.png,  opentestdrive.com/demo/test/3.png                          opentestdrive.com/demo/test/2.png                            opentestdrive.com/demo/test/1.png

Comment: i have added two jars  struts-2-core.jar.....struts1.3.0 jar..we have used two struts..